# My blend file immediately crashes and closes out whenever I render. What are the ways that I can recover my file?

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine, error

My blend file continues to keep crashing the program right as I hit render. I have kept the same settings using cycles Optix render with my 2080 Super. There is no error message as the program immediately closes as if nothing happened but any changes I make to the file remain and even viewport rendering still works perfectly fine. The file does not take up too much memory although I can't tell how much VRAM usage there is during the render.

Comment: Have you tried using a different denoiser (NLM or OpenImage instead of OptiX)?

Comment: @ChristopherBennett OptiX is not a denoiser. It it a language for communicating with the GPU. However, I do remember that GPU denoising was added recently, and that may be malfunctioning.

Comment: make sure you have not hidden any heavy meshes in viewport that are visible at render.
this happens sometimes if you have heavy sculpted meshes.

As for the recovery , you can recover the files from file>recover>autosave.

Comment: you could run blender from the console (cmd.exe) - this way you will get some diagnostic output when it crashes which might help in finding the root of your problem